# Работа с окном формы

Tags: delphi

Всем доброго времени суток.

Имеется приложени е(игра), запущенное в полнооконноом режиме (курсор не используется в явном виде, т.е. скрыт). Имеется приложение, написанное на делфи и программно расположенное поверх всех окон (также спрятанное из таскбара). Требуется.

1. Чтобы курсор не появлялся в игре при выходе его за пределы формы приложении (в идеале отключить/спрятать его совсем при запуске приложения). Пробовал `ShowCursor(False)` и `Screen.Cursor := crNone;` в обработчике `TForm1.FormPaint`, загрузку пустого курсора из файла при создании формы, но при движении мышкой курсор все равно появляется в игре на некоторое время и затем только исчезает.
2. Чтобы при попадании мыши в пределы формы и клике игра не сворачивалась. Пробовал `form1.Enabled:=false` но не помогло.

Пробовал изучить ловушки, но не понял как ими пользоваться.

Comment: Объясните попонятнее, что вам надо

Comment: курсор при выходе за пределы формы, которая имеет маленький размер, появляется в игре и исчезает, надо чтобы этого не было
также при нажатии мышки в игре по области, где расположена форма, игра сворачивается, это также необходимо убрать

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

   var
    rtemp,rtemp2,rtemp3,rtemp4,rtemp5,rtemp6:thandle;
    wx,wy,ww,wh:integer;
    begin

    windows.SetParent(form1.Handle,getdesktopwindow);
    SetWindowPos(form1.handle,HWND_TOPMOST,0,0,form1.Width,form1.Height,SWP_SHOWWINDOW or SWP_NOOWNERZORDER or SWP_NOZORDER);
    SetWindowLong(form1.handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(form1.handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) or WS_EX_LAYERED {or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT} or WS_EX_TOPMOST);
    form1.show;
    SetWindowPos(form10.handle,HWND_TOPMOST,0,0,form10.Width,form10.Height,SWP_SHOWWINDOW {or SWP_NOOWNERZORDER or SWP_NOZORDER});

 wx:=200; wy:=40; //левый верхний край  окна на десктоп
  ww:=800; wh:=600; //размеры окна на десктоп

  with form1 do begin
   rTemp := CreaterectRgn(0, 0, screen.Width, screen.Height);
   rTemp2 := CreaterectRgn(wx,wy+5+13,wx+ww,wy+wh-17);

   rTemp3 := CreaterectRgn(33,wy+25,33+72,wy+25+93);
   rTemp4 := CreaterectRgn(33,wy+118+46,33+72,wy+118+46+93);
   rTemp5 := CreaterectRgn(33,wy+257+46,33+72,wy+257+46+93);
   rTemp6 := CreaterectRgn(33,wy+396+46,33+72,wy+396+46+93);

   CombineRgn(rTemp, rTemp, rTemp2, RGN_DIFF);
   CombineRgn(rTemp, rTemp, rTemp3, RGN_DIFF);
   CombineRgn(rTemp, rTemp, rTemp4, RGN_DIFF);
   CombineRgn(rTemp, rTemp, rTemp5, RGN_DIFF);
   CombineRgn(rTemp, rTemp, rTemp6, RGN_DIFF);
   SetWindowRgn(form1.Handle, rTemp, True);
   DeleteObject(rTemp);
   DeleteObject(rTemp2);
   DeleteObject(rTemp3);
   DeleteObject(rTemp4);
   DeleteObject(rTemp5);
   DeleteObject(rTemp6);
  end;

  Application.OnIdle := OnIdle;

 end;
```

Comment: спасибо, но помогло вот это:
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
Scr.Handle:=GetWindowDC(GetDeskTopWindow);
with Scr do
    begin
      Pen.Color:=cllime;
      MoveTo...